# Elastic Search multiple AND + OR query

Tags: elasticsearch

My document schema is as follows.

**Tweet**

```
Id
Title
Body
Privacy -> Values can only be ["Me", "Anyone", "Team"]
UserId
```

Now I only want to retrieve all tweets with the Title containing "chicken sandwich" that has the privacy of "Anyone" or "Team". However, within that same query, I only want Tweets that have a privacy of "Me" to be returned if the UserId of that Tweet is "1456".

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "title": {
                                        "query": "chicken_sandwhich"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "should": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "privacy": {
                                        "value": "Anyone"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "privacy": {
                                        "value": "Team"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "privacy": {
                                        "value": "Me"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "userId.keyword": {
                                        "value": "my_user_id"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

How can I structure that query? I have been struggling and just need help on what the type of query I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need two `must`s wrapped within one `should` query:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "Title": "chicken sandwich"
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "Privacy.keyword": [
                    "Anyone",
                    "Team"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "Privacy.keyword": {
                    "value": "Me"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "UserId": {
                    "value": 1456
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to consider `query_string`. which would let you write your query in a straightforward manner, like:

```
Title:"chicken sandwich" AND (
  Privacy:(Anyone OR Team)
  OR (Privacy:Me AND UserId:1456)
)
```

or in the actual format:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "Title:\"chicken sandwich\" AND (Privacy:(Anyone OR Team) OR (Privacy:Me AND UserId:1456))",
    }
  }
}
```

See documentation here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html